# How i can stop app music when i minimize the app or current window on .NET MAUI

Tags: .net, maui

My app has background music. I'm trying stop music when current window is minimized. The app is for mobile.

I try it :

```cs
public partial class StartPage : ContentPage
{
    public StartPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        
        this.Disappearing += stopMusic;
    }

    private void stopMusic(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        mediaElement.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: use the App [Stopped](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/app-lifecycle?view=net-maui-7.0) event

Comment: To handle the app going in background I like a lot [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74595179/10404482)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying stop music when current window is minimized. The app is for
> mobile.

Yes, if you want to do something the current window is minimized for your mobile, you can add code on method `Stopped`  of Cross-platform lifecycle events.

Please refer to the following code:

```
public partial class App : Application 
{
      public App()
      {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new AppShell();
      }

    protected override Window CreateWindow(IActivationState activationState)
    {
        Window window = base.CreateWindow(activationState);

        //
        window.Created += (s, e) =>
        {
            // Custom logic

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("-----------------> Created");
        };

        // event `Stopped` will be triggered while minimizing the current page
        window.Stopped += (s, e) =>
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("-----------------> Stopped");

        };

        return window;
    }
}
```